# Why doesn't makefile function properly?

Tags: makefile

I have this makefile:

```
src = $(notdir $(wildcard src/*.cpp))
obj = $(src:.cpp=.o)
libname ?= libtest
importlib_flags = -ldl -lboost_filesystem

parser: $(obj)
    g++ -o $@ $^

%.o: src/%.cpp
ifeq ($<,src/$(libname).cpp)
    g++ -fpic -c $(libname).cpp -o $(libname).o
    g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,$(libname).so.1 -o $(libname).so.1.0.1 $(libname).o -lc
else
    g++ -c $< -o $@ $(if $(findstring importlib, $<), $(importlib_flags))
endif

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.so* parser
```

After I run make, I get this:

```
g++ -c src/libtest.cpp -o libtest.o 
g++ -c src/importlib.cpp -o importlib.o  -ldl -lboost_filesystem
g++ -c src/token.cpp -o token.o 
g++ -c src/main.cpp -o main.o 
g++ -o parser libtest.o importlib.o token.o main.o
```

First line implies makefile goes to `else` branch, but it should go to `ifeq` because $< expands to `src/libtest.cpp` which is equal to `src/$(libname).cpp` after being expanded. I don't set `libname` via command line. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the expansion happens before the rule is actually run, therefore the `$<` is probably expanded to empty. I.e. the makefile parses the if/else before it runs the rule.

Then when the rule is run, it has "pre-selected" the else part since when it did the decision `$<` was not what it is during the rule.

So what you can do is use shell script (I am assuming bash), somthing like:

```
%.o: src/%.cpp
    if [[ "$<" == "src/$(libname).cpp" ]] ; then \
        g++ -fpic -c $(libname).cpp -o $(libname).o ; \
        g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,$(libname).so.1 -o $(libname).so.1.0.1 $(libname).o -lc ; \
    else \
        g++ -c $< -o $@ $(if $(findstring importlib, $<), $(importlib_flags)) ; \
    fi
```

**Note** bash/shell vars are written like `$${shell_var}` and makefile vars are `$(make_var)` - just incase you need them!

Also note if you want to specifically use BASH add this to the top of your makefile:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
```

Comment: `the expansion happens before the rule is actually run` Do not confuse "an expansion before run" and "an expansion on the first pass". The recipe (rule body) is expanded **just before** run (when `$<` is set), but `ifeq` is **NOT** the part of a recipe, so it gets expanded on the first pass. And so it fails.

Comment: @Matt thanks for the clarification, I did not explain it very clearly I was trying to go for simple (and probably failed)

Comment: Of course, the best course of action would be to write a separate, specific rule for the `$(libname).o` case, thus getting rid of the conditional altogether. Also another for `$(libname).so.1.0.1`, instead of making that an extra output of a rule for a different target.